# Angular Differences Between Two Models

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an angular application which uses a significantly large shared model. Currently, when a user presses save the entire model is posted to a RESTful service. Ideally I would only like to post the fields that have changed. Since this is a shared model I do not have access to form validation states such as dirty/pristine etc. The idea I can think of is to have two models, the original and the modified and compare these.

**Original Model**

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    },
    {
      "id": "789",
      "number": "123 456-7890"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null
}
```

**Changed Model**

```
{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "isAlive": true,
    "age": 50,
    "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "number": "1234567890"
    },
    {
        "id": "456",
        "number": "646 555-4567"
    },
    {
        "id": "789",
        "number": "123 456-7890"
    }
    ],
    "children": [],
    "spouse": null
}
```

**Data Posted - This is what I need!**

```
{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "age": 50,
    "phoneNumbers": [
    {
        "id":"123",
        "number": "1234567890"
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this? I need the changed fields including any fields called id!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like this.  Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jyyyLaot/

```
function filter(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = {};
    for(key in obj1) {
        if(obj2[key] != obj1[key]) result[key] = obj2[key];
        if(typeof obj2[key] == 'array' && typeof obj1[key] == 'array') 
            result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
        if(typeof obj2[key] == 'object' && typeof obj1[key] == 'object') 
            result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    }
    return result;
}
```